# Lua Webservice Connectivity

Tags: lua

Is there any possibility to connect webservice using Lua Language in Scite editor? Otherwise Please help me how to connect webservice with Lua Language.

Comment: This question isn't better than your previous one on the same matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033065/lua-language-programming-closed, please edit.

Comment: Note that unless you are trying to write a SciTE extension in Lua that consumes a web service, the SciTE editor itself is not related to this question at all.

Answer (score 5):

There are Lua modules that support connectivity at various protocol levels. At the lowest level, and probably required by most other solutions, is [LuaSocket](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/luasocket/).

At a much higher level you will find modules like [LuaCURL](http://luacurl.luaforge.net/).

Also, the [Kepler Project](http://www.keplerproject.org/) supports the implementation of web applications and services in Lua.

Finally, a lot of general "How do I use Lua to do this" kind of information is available at the [Lua User's Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/).

Comment: The LuaCURL link seems to be broken.